# CodeIgniter can't find session userdata present on db

Tags: c#, codeigniter, session

I have a c# client application that does two web requests with different urls, sending a json string and receiving a json string to be deserialized.
This is the code of them:

```
private CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();
public string AskInfo(string data, string url) {
        string result = null;
        try {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookie;
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())) {
                streamWriter.Write(data);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            logger.Debug("Error while asking infos from server", e.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This is my config.php file:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

My controller has this constructor:
(I've also tried to autoload session library with the same result)

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('session');
}
```

This is the code of my controller's methods:
In the first call: http://mywebserver/mycontroller/offerupdate/ with the following code:

```
public function offerUpdate() {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        $session_data = array(
            'fileName' => 'prova.exe',
            'member' => $data['member'],
            'versions' => $data['versions']
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
        log_message('history', 'Offer Update: Session has user data: '.$this->session->has_userdata('member'));

        $response['updatable'] = TRUE;
        $response['file'] = $this->session->userdata('fileName');
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response);
}
```

In the second one: http://mywebserver/mycontroller/offerMD5 with this code:

```
public function offerMD5() {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    log_message('history', 'Offer MD5: Session has user data: '.$this->session->has_userdata('member'));
    $file = BASEPATH.$data['file'];
    $response['MD5'] = md5_file($file);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Here is my question: why my logger print:

```
HISTORY - date, time --> Offer Update: Session has user data: 1
HISTORY - date, time --> Offer MD5: Session has user data:
```

this fileds "Offer MD5: Session has user data: " is just empty, not true (1) nor false (0), like above.
Practically CodeIgniter can't tell me if the data I need are present or not.
I suppose CodeIgniter does not close the session because it is still in my db. So, why have i that logger log?
Everything is working but the session's userdata doesn't.
Seems I have left out something but i can't understand what.

**EDITED:**
this is the profiler output:

```
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:33 --> Config Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:33 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2017-04-13 10:09:33 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:33 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:33 --> URI Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:33 --> Router Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:33 --> Output Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:33 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2017-04-13 10:09:33 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:33 --> Input Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:33 --> Language Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:33 --> Loader Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:33 --> Controller Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:33 --> Helper loaded: url_helper
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:33 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:33 --> Session: Class initialized using 'database' driver.
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:33 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2017-04-13 10:09:33 --> Total execution time: 0.0312
```

And then for the second web request:

```
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:35 --> Config Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:35 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2017-04-13 10:09:35 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:35 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:35 --> URI Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:35 --> Router Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:35 --> Output Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:35 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2017-04-13 10:09:35 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:35 --> Input Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:35 --> Language Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:35 --> Loader Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:35 --> Controller Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:35 --> Helper loaded: url_helper
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:35 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:35 --> Session: Class initialized using 'database' driver.
INFO - 2017-04-13 10:09:35 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2017-04-13 10:09:35 --> Total execution time: 0.0780
```

It seems that codeigniter restart everything at every request. Now I think I'm using the wrong logic to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a couple of ideas, try setting

```
$config['sess_match_useragent']=FALSE;
```

I've heard of issues with browsers not doing what they are supposed to with the cookie.

Try also enabling the profiler to see what's happening with the session since by default that information is hidden.

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

Outside of this, I would almost argue that the CodeIgniter forums are a better resource than SO for this specific issue you might want to scour.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my question to show the profiler output. I can't understand the cause of this, maybe it's c#, not CodeIgniter, so it's why I ask here